# Autolink web on TextView has wrong result

Tags: android, html, textview, autolink

I'm using a `TextView` component in `ListView`. Sometimes i have a links on my text in `TextView` and i want to open browser by clicking on them.
All links in my text have a tag:

> This is an example of my text. [This is link](http://blabla.com)

For that purposes i use:

`textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(someTextString));
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
textView.setLinksClickable(true);`

Everything is fine, but if i put some text:

> This is a sample text. link.thing

On that case `link.thing` was selected as link.
How can i make clickable only links between `<a></a>` tags?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
android:text="@string/Your_String_Contain"
```

Now this plays vital role

```
<string name="Your_String_Contain">This is an example of my text  <a href="http://www.yourlink.com">This is link</a></string>
```

Then just call `setMovementMethod` ,

```
TextView Tv_App_Link=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Your_Textview_Id);
Tv_App_Link.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

this way you can set link it will automatically find out links

```
  String myHtmlStr = "<a href=www.google.com>click here</a>";

            setTextViewHTML(myTextView, myHtmlStr);
```

this methods you can implements to achieve this

```
 protected void setTextViewHTML(TextView text, String html) {
            CharSequence sequence = Html.fromHtml(html);
            SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(sequence);
            URLSpan[] urls = strBuilder.getSpans(0, sequence.length(), URLSpan.class);
            for (URLSpan span : urls) {
                makeLinkClickable(strBuilder, span);
            }
            text.setText(strBuilder);
        } 

protected void makeLinkClickable(SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder, final URLSpan span) {

            int start = strBuilder.getSpanStart(span);
            int end = strBuilder.getSpanEnd(span);
            int flags = strBuilder.getSpanFlags(span);
            TouchableSpan touchableSpan = new TouchableSpan() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View widget) {

                  //your logic
                }
            };
            touchableSpan.setURLSpan(span);
            strBuilder.setSpan(touchableSpan, start, end, flags);
            strBuilder.removeSpan(span);
        }
```